# How to allow screen sharing via wifi hotspot (using vino)?

Tags: vnc, vino

I am trying to share the screen of my computer (Ubuntu 19.04). The computer is set up to provide a wifi hotspot. The idea is that VNC clients connect to my computer via the hotspot. I need this because I am planning to operate my computer at remote places where no other networks exist.

If I go to the GNOME sharing preferences (screen sharing using Vino), I cannot turn on screen sharing. The slider / switch just does not allow turning it on.

If I disable the wifi hotspot and connect my computer to an existing wifi, I can turn on the screen sharing with no problems.

Any ideas what's wrong, and how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like gnome cannot handle wifi hotspots properly it may be a bug, but looks more like they forgot.

It is possible to bypass the problem launching vino manually.

This is what i made on 20.04 who shares the same problem.

Inside this file:

/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.Vino.gschema.xml

find this:

```
   <key name='network-interface' type='s'>
     <summary>Network interface for listening</summary>
     <description>
       If not set, the server will listen on all network interfaces.

       Set this if you want to accept connections only from some specific
       network interface. For example, eth0, wifi0, lo and so on.
     </description>
     <default>''</default>
   </key>
```

In the line:

default>''</default

between the '' place the name of you network interface, to find it type on a terminal.

```
    sudo ip r
```

After that just launch Vino manually.

```
    /usr/lib/vino/vino-server
```

Comment: Thanks for this hint. However, I don't have a network-interfaces key in this file on my machine. Those Gnome schema settings seem to change from time to time, so messing with them may not always work.
Also, I believe the underlying issue is being fixed in Gnome 42, see here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/-/issues/595